# How to properly unit test a domain service?

Tags: unit-testing, domain-driven-design

I have a domain service

```
public class BlobService{
    private FooRepository repo;
    public BlobService(FooRepository repo){
        this.repo = repo;
    }
    public void DoSomething(int id1,int id2){
        var foo1 = repo.Get(id1);
        var foo2 = repo.Get(id2);
        var valueSomething = foo1.GetValueSomething();
        foo2.SetValueSomething(valueSomething );
        repo.Save(foo2);
        DomainEvent.Raise(new ValueSomethingChanged(foo2));
    }
}
```

Here , the methods

- repo.Get, repo.Save are tested by integration test (because there is a rdbms behind)
- GetValueSomething , SetValueSomething and Raise by unit tests

So what will my unit test for BlobService look like ?

- Mocking repo, foo1 and foo2 and checking the good methods are called. DomainEvent is static but really simple
- do integration test instead : send real implementation for repo, request it and check the foo2 value.
- something else

?

Comment: Hey remi.  If my answer is satisfactory, could you upvote and mark it as answer?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I see no value in testing if repo methods are called. Using this feature of mocks is useful when we test a component that is intended to interact with (be a wrapper of) some external system. This is not the case here.

Tests, whatever type you use, should have AAA structure. Arrange - prepare some test data/state. Act - call your service. Assert - verify the outcome (final state) is correct. You use domain events - this means testing also if correct events were raised. If you used Event Sourcing - you would do arrange part as playing events and assert part would contain only checking events raised.

Integration test are slower then unit test. You need them if your persistence leaks into the domain or contrary. For example, when you rely on lazy loading features of ORM (which is not very DDD-like by the way) or use stored procedures.

Well, don't assume too quickly that it doesn't leak ;)

Answer (score 0):

These are some relevant DDD testing principles I've learned along the way:

- The only thing you need to test is *behavior, not state.*  (This is supported by Udi Dahan if you check out how NServiceBus handler/saga tests work.)
- Fast-running tests are critical.  Slow-running integration tests are not worth the effort because they are slow and easily prone to breakage.  The effort to maintain wasn't worth the return for my project.

(Again, these are specific to my project - YMMV.)

So with that in mind, here's how I would test your class.  (Note that I have killed the static `DomainEvents` class and replaced it with `IBus` because it makes testing way easier in my experience.):

```
public class BlobService
{
    private IBus _bus;
    private IFooRepository _repo;

    public BlobService(IBus bus, IFooRepository repo)
    {
        _bus = bus;
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public void DoSomething(int id1, int id2)
    {
        var foo1 = _repo.Get(id1);
        var foo2 = _repo.Get(id2);
        var valueSomething = foo1.GetValueSomething();
        foo2.SetValueSomething(valueSomething);
        _repo.Save(foo2);

        _bus.Publish(new ValueSomethingChanged(foo2));
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class BlobRepositoryTests
{
    [Test]
    public void DoSomething_RaisesValueSomethingChanged()
    {
        // Arrange:
        var bus = new MockBus();  // just stores the events in a publicly accessible list
        var repo = new MockBlobRepository(); // does whatever you need it to do (or use Moq, etc)
        var service = new BlobService(bus, repo);

        // Act:
        service.DoSomething(1, 2);

        // Assert:
        var @event = bus.Events.OfType<ValueSomethingChanged>().Single();
        Assert.That(() => @event.Property1, Is.EqualTo(someExpectedValue));
        Assert.That(() => @event.Property2, Is.EqualTo(someOtherExpectedValue));
    }
}
```

Comment: So how would you test that the service calls SetValueSomething ?

Comment: It doesn't need to be tested.  It's an internal implementation detail.  Let's say that you discover (as I did) that it's not even necessary to have those repositories and domain objects and you can just hit the DB directly via an ORM.  If that happens, then you will have to do major refactoring on your tests while the actual business logic of the system has not changed.  That's why you shouldn't test it.

Comment: So, the test you wrote is the only one you'd do ?

Comment: Yeah.  Counter-intuitive, isn't it?  But I learned the hard way that you should only test the way I've described above (at least for my project).  One possible change is that your foo object can call DomainEvents.Raise instead of the Service.  That way you're implicitly testing that SetValueSomething is called, but then that's the beauty of the technique described above: your test wouldn't have to change at all.

Comment: Also, in my case if SetValueSomething isn't called, that is going to be caught almost immediately by QA and it's not a common mistake to make.  So I'm factoring in the human element in that it's not a mistake that is easy to make and difficult to catch.  In my case, the risk of not calling SetValueSomething is not worth the cost of testing an internal part of the service.  (And I virtually never test internal stuff to a class.)

Comment: So you're not doing tdd, because your test will pass as soon as you write "_bus.Publish(new ValueSomethingChanged(foo2));"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49890/discussion-between-josh-kodroff-and-remi-bourgarel)